# Html5 video is not playing automatically on page load in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, html5-video

i am working on wordpress website and i just put a video by using HMTL5 video tag, but problem here is video is working autoplay on all browser other then chrome, please can anybody tells me why is not automatically playing on onload in chrome browser.

The code which i am using for is this.

```
<video id="video1" width="300" autoplay controls>
    <source src="https://www.***.com/wp-content/themes/***/videos/***-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
</video>
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow the video to autoplay on load unless it's muted (thankfully). See the duplicate I marked for more information

Comment: Maybe (and I repeat it: MAYBE) because of this? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: but its working when open website in chrome and then i refresh with F5

Comment: Use `muted` in <video> tag.